# numerical stability: LU decomposition

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to evaluate the numerical stability of LU decomposition.
I implemented code in java to calculate the inverse matrix with LU.
I made 3 attemps.
a) mantissa 4
b) mantissa 6
c) maschine accuracy

a and b use a method to round the values of each step to the given mantissa.
If i compare my results, the values of a and b are similar. But differ in value in a range of 20 to 1000. Both are not even close to the result of attemp c. But c is very close to a result calculated by mathematica. So I think the implementation is correct.
But if I go down with mantissa from 16 to 6 in steps of 1, the result changes dramaticly.
How do I evaluate the LU decomposition? It seems very unstable to me. But what are the reasons for such a behavior?

Sincerly,
Heinz

Comment: More details about the matrix being inverted would be helpful.

Comment: LU without pivoting/permutation is unstable.

Comment: @user251257: While LU factorization (Gaussian elimination without pivoting) can be unstable, a useful category where it is stable is on column strictly diagonally dominant matrices.

Comment: @hardmath that's true. Overall one needs more details for an useful analysis.